# How do I scrape titles using Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Ahoy everyone, I am learning Beautiful Soup and I am having a hard time scraping titles from [this website](https://www.prace.cz/hledat/?searchForm%5Blocality_codes%5D=&searchForm%5Bprofs%5D=&searchForm%5Bother%5D=Angli%C4%8Dtina&searchForm%5Bemployment_type_codes%5D%5B%5D=201300001&searchForm%5Bemployment_type_codes%5D%5B%5D=201300002&searchForm%5Bemployment_type_codes%5D%5B%5D=201300004&searchForm%5Bminimal_salary%5D=&searchForm%5Beducation%5D=&searchForm%5Bsuitable_for%5D=&searchForm%5Bsearch%5D=).

This is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.prace.cz/hledat/?searchForm%5Blocality_codes%5D=&searchForm%5Bprofs%5D=&searchForm%5Bother%5D=Angli%C4%8Dtina&searchForm%5Bemployment_type_codes%5D%5B%5D=201300001&searchForm%5Bemployment_type_codes%5D%5B%5D=201300002&searchForm%5Bemployment_type_codes%5D%5B%5D=201300004&searchForm%5Bminimal_salary%5D=&searchForm%5Beducation%5D=&searchForm%5Bsuitable_for%5D=&searchForm%5Bsearch%5D="
web = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(web.content, "html.parser")

vyber_pozic = soup.find_all("li",class_="search-result__advert")

for i in vyber_pozic:  
    nazev_pozice = i.find("a",class_="link").text
print(i)
```

And I get: nazev_pozice = i.find("a",class_="link").text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

I would like to get a list of those blue titles. Is there someone who can tell me how should the code look like?[I want to extract the Title from this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbHaF.png)

I tried scraping based on h3 and a but non of it works.

Answer (score 0):

Not all `"li"`s have `"a"` in them. But the ones that don't seem to be the ads (I assume you don't want them). So you can just check if the `"a"` is found before getting text from it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.prace.cz/hledat/?searchForm%5Blocality_codes%5D=&searchForm%5Bprofs%5D=&searchForm%5Bother%5D=Angli%C4%8Dtina&searchForm%5Bemployment_type_codes%5D%5B%5D=201300001&searchForm%5Bemployment_type_codes%5D%5B%5D=201300002&searchForm%5Bemployment_type_codes%5D%5B%5D=201300004&searchForm%5Bminimal_salary%5D=&searchForm%5Beducation%5D=&searchForm%5Bsuitable_for%5D=&searchForm%5Bsearch%5D="
web = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(web.content, "html.parser")

vyber_pozic = soup.find_all("li",class_="search-result__advert")

for i in vyber_pozic:
    title = i.find("a",class_="link")
    if title:
        print(title.text.strip())
```

output:

```
Vývojář/Analytik .NET (C#)
OBSLUHA WOKIN NOODLE BISTRO
Vývojář/Analytik C++
Vývojář/Analytik JAVA
Špecialista porovnávania poistenia so SLOVENČINOU
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't always get data when searching by the 'a' tag. You just need to handle the 'AttributeError' error:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.prace.cz/hledat/?searchForm%5Blocality_codes%5D=&searchForm%5Bprofs%5D=&searchForm%5Bother%5D=Angli%C4%8Dtina&searchForm%5Bemployment_type_codes%5D%5B%5D=201300001&searchForm%5Bemployment_type_codes%5D%5B%5D=201300002&searchForm%5Bemployment_type_codes%5D%5B%5D=201300004&searchForm%5Bminimal_salary%5D=&searchForm%5Beducation%5D=&searchForm%5Bsuitable_for%5D=&searchForm%5Bsearch%5D="

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
}

web = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(web.content, "html.parser")

vyber_pozic = soup.find_all("li",class_="search-result__advert")
for i in vyber_pozic:
    try:
        nazev_pozice = i.find("a", class_="link").text
        print(nazev_pozice)
    except AttributeError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for the answers. But this works only for this specific site, when I try to use this technique for another, similar website, even with "if variable:", it doesn't work. Could you tell me the steps how to do it if I want to apply similar steps on a [different web](https://beta.www.jobs.cz/prace/moravskoslezsky-kraj/?cacheKey=d06a498d-7dd9-4416-bbe0-4f2276fe95cd)?

Here is my code which prints *nothing*, and I don't know why:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://beta.www.jobs.cz/prace/moravskoslezsky-kraj/?cacheKey=d06a498d-7dd9-4416-bbe0-4f2276fe95cd"
web = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(web.content, "html.parser")

vyber_pozic = soup.find_all("article",class_="SearchResultCard  ")

for i in vyber_pozic:
 
 pozice = i.find("h2", class_="SearchResultCard__title ")
 if pozice:
    print(pozice.text.strip())
```